# sbt - copy managed libraries to lib

Tags: sbt

How can I copy managed libraries to a specific folder with Scala Build Tool?

For example:

All the jars from this managed library, would be put in 'project/lib'

```
libraryDependencies += "com.miglayout" % "miglayout-swt" % "4.2"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution. Pretty simple actually.

Add the following to build.sbt

This will copy the jars to project/lib_managed/jars//*.jar

```
retrieveManaged := true
```

I'm not sure about how to specify a specific folder, but this is good enough to get the jars under the project folder.